# Which keys are free / unmapped by default in VIM?

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a list of keys which aren't mapped by default in vim? / gvim?

Comment: Something like [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Unused_keys)?

Comment: Yes, this could be posted as an answer

Comment: Which vi implementation do you refer at @ideasman42 ?

Comment: gVIM I suppose (it seems mostly the same as VIM).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Free Keys

### Normal Mode

- `<C-K>`
- `<C-_>` (Same as `<C-/>`)
- `<C-[>` (Same as `<Esc>`)
- `<C-@>` (Same as `<C-Space>`)

### Visual Mode

- `<C-T>`
- `<C-K>`
- `<C-@>` (Same as `<C-Space>`)
- `<C-O>`
- `Q`
- `Z`
- `.`
- `<C-R>`
- `<C-_>` (Same as `<C-/>`)
- `<C-^>`
- `&`
- `<C-I>` (This is the `<Tab>` key)

### Insert Mode

- `<C-_>` (Same as `<C-/>`)
- `<C-Z>` (Unless `insertmode` is set)
- `<C-B`

### Command-line Mode

- `<C-@>` (Same as `<C-Space>`)
- `<C-O>`
- `<C-Z>`
- `<C-_>` (Only active in default vim if `allowrevins` is set, for right-to-left languages)
- `<C-X>`

### All Modes

- All function keys
- All `ALT` key combinations
- `<C-S>`

---

Used source: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Unused_keys

This link points to a page listing unused keys in vim.

This page also lists keys that are synonyms of other keys in terms of functionality, meaning that these keys can be safely remapped.

Comment: This answer doesn't mention alt/shift keys.

Answer (score 2):

[This list](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/Tech/vi.html) shows the unbound keys in standard vi; unbound keys extracted from the complete list of all the bound keys in the link:

```
g   UNBOUND
q   UNBOUND
v   UNBOUND
K   UNBOUND
V   UNBOUND
#   UNBOUND
*   UNBOUND
\   UNBOUND
=   UNBOUND
^A  UNBOUND
^C  UNBOUND
^I  (TAB) UNBOUND
^K  UNBOUND
^O  UNBOUND
^V  UNBOUND
^W  UNBOUND
^X  UNBOUND
^[  (ESC) cancel started command; otherwise UNBOUND
^_  UNBOUND
^?  (DELETE) UNBOUND
```